# Get the name of application in focus (on Mac)

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a requirement where, I need to have the name of the running application in focus.
I am using C++/Qt/Carbon.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetFrontProcess](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetFrontProcess)

Comment: Notice that as this is highly platform specific, Qt does not help you out. Instead you will have to use a Carbon specific function, as pointed out by NSD.